# Isotope active class when using select menu

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-isotope

I am using Metafizzy's Isotope plugin and have it set up to filter using a select menu as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/trewknowledge/jJZEN/

```
    $(function() {

    var $container = $('#container'),
        $select = $('#filters select');

    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item'
    });

    $select.change(function() {
        var filters = $(this).val();
;
        $container.isotope({
            filter: filters
        });
    });

});​
```

What I am trying to figure out is how I would add a highlight/active class to the selected elements when the filters variable is already being used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
$select.change(function() {
        var filters = $(this).val();
        $('.container div').removeClass('active');
        $(filters).addClass('active');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: filters
        });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jJZEN/17/)

also you can try `<option value=".item">All</option>` instead of `<option value="*">All</option>` which is too slow.

```
$select.change(function() {
        var filters = $(this).val();
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        if (filters != '.item') {
            $( filters).addClass('active');
        }
        $container.isotope({
            filter: filters
        });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jJZEN/18/)